# Memory issues: Tempdb using Almost all of the buffer cache

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, tempdb

On one of the servers I am working on today, i see that almost all of the buffer cache is filled by tempdb.
As a result memory is very low on the server.

CPU
[image]

Tempdb:

[image]

Version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU13) (KB4456287) - 12.0.5590.1 (X64)
>   Aug  1 2018 01:23:36   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

4 data files = 4096 MB
1 Log file = 1536MB

My issue is that TEMPDB uses 13GB of my buffer cache. 
I checked the objects in tempdb, the biggest ones where my sp_blitz temp tables, which where not that big.

RCSI is not enabled for any database so should not be a version store problem.

No open transactions

No open cursors.

When i execute checkpoint on tempdb, it takes around 30 seconds, but finishes.

When i execute dbcc dropcleanbuffers
the presence of tempdb in the buffer cache gets reduced tto sometimes 1 GB sometimes 4gb
30 seconds later it is back in its full glory of 13GB

For example:

```
dbcc dropcleanbuffers


DECLARE @total_buffer INT;

SELECT @total_buffer = cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
WHERE RTRIM([object_name]) LIKE '%Buffer Manager'
AND counter_name = 'Database Pages';

;WITH src AS
(
SELECT 
database_id, db_buffer_pages = COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
--WHERE database_id BETWEEN 5 AND 32766
GROUP BY database_id
)
SELECT
[db_name] = CASE [database_id] WHEN 32767 
THEN 'Resource DB' 
ELSE DB_NAME([database_id]) END,
db_buffer_pages,
db_buffer_MB = db_buffer_pages / 128,
db_buffer_percent = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,3), 
db_buffer_pages * 100.0 / @total_buffer)
FROM src
ORDER BY db_buffer_MB DESC;
```

Result right after:

```
db_name db_buffer_pages db_buffer_MB    db_buffer_percent
tempdb  620627  4848    58.096
```

30 sec later:

```
db_name db_buffer_pages db_buffer_MB    db_buffer_percent
tempdb  1313835 10264   83.560
```

Tempdb buffer cache usage at its peak (its_over_9000.jpeg)
[image]

Check objects in tempdb:

```
use tempdb 

go
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
GROUP BY  t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY  TotalSpaceKB desc
```

**Top 4 Values:**

```
TableName   SchemaName  RowCounts   TotalSpaceKB    UsedSpaceKB UnusedSpaceKB
#A3B2C869   dbo 0   72  16  56
#A52E4149   dbo 0   72  16  56
#A59B10DB   dbo 0   72  16  56
#A68F3514   dbo 0   72  16  56
```

for  a total of a whopping 74 Objects.

I do see a lot of (375 000+!!!) pages with 7965 bytes free space,  and only one row count in my memory buffer. 
Query used:

```
select * from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
where database_id = 2
order by free_space_in_bytes desc
```

**e.g.**

```
file_id page_id page_level  allocation_unit_id  page_type   row_count   free_space_in_bytes
1   109763  0   71635384526569472   INDEX_PAGE  1   7965
```

but even more with 40 bytes free space (1M) see below.

**Filtering some more:**

```
select page_type,free_space_in_bytes,  count(*)as counter from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
where database_id = 2
group by page_type, free_space_in_bytes
having count(*) > 500
order by free_space_in_bytes desc
```

[image]

**Question**

Why is my tempdb filling up so fast after issueing dbcc dropcleanbuffers?
Am I missing something, what should i check?

**UPDATE 30/11/2018**

Afer setting TEMPDB as 4 files of 512 MB, and restarting the server,
the MB in buffer seems to be lower. 
However it is still 6GB.

[image]

Any other ideas on what to do / check now?

**Extra info:**

Tracestatus

[image]

Examples of constant executed queries captured by profiler:

```
exec sp_reset_connection 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE Error IS NULL
```

Some connections use serializable:

```
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level serializable
```

Some don't

```
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

Max mem is a bit on the low side:

[image]

DBCC PAGE Checks:
DBCC TRACEON (3604);

DBCC PAGE (2, 5, 474258, 3);
DBCC TRACEOFF (3604);

```
bpage = 0x00000016AA16C000          bhash = 0x0000000000000000          bpageno = (5:474258)
bdbid = 2                           breferences = 0                     bcputicks = 0
bsampleCount = 0                    bUse1 = 1952                        bstat = 0x109
blog = 0xcdcdcdcd                   bnext = 0x0000000000000000          

PAGE HEADER:


Page @0x00000016AA16C000

m_pageId = (5:474258)               m_headerVersion = 1                 m_type = 3
m_typeFlagBits = 0x0                m_level = 0                         m_flagBits = 0x8020
m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = -1778255884                                m_indexId (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 255
Metadata: AllocUnitId = 71941054260314112                                Metadata: PartitionId = 0
Metadata: IndexId = -1              Metadata: ObjectId = 0              m_prevPage = (0:0)
m_nextPage = (0:0)                  pminlen = 0                         m_slotCnt = 1
m_freeCnt = 40                      m_freeData = 8150                   m_reservedCnt = 0
m_lsn = (5148:180860:473)           m_xactReserved = 0                  m_xdesId = (0:0)
m_ghostRecCnt = 0                   m_tornBits = 0                      DB Frag ID = 1

Allocation Status

GAM (5:2) = NOT ALLOCATED           SGAM (5:3) = NOT ALLOCATED          PFS (5:469104) = 0x4 100_PCT_FULL
DIFF (5:6) = NOT CHANGED            ML (5:7) = NOT MIN_LOGGED           


Blob row at: Page (5:474258) Slot 0 Length: 8054 Type: 3 (DATA)

Blob Id:2794796220416



000000464FAFA06E:  0044002b  006f0051  00550038  00520058 +.D.Q.o.8.U.X.R.
...
```

@Craig your output:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you ever find the root cause of this issue?
I'm having some similar issues. My guess it's due to heavily use of BULK INSERT but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but the join between sys.allocation_units and sys.partitions isn't quite right per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-allocation-units-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  EG

```
select bd.file_id, bd.page_id, p.*
from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors bd
left join sys.allocation_units au
 on bd.allocation_unit_id = au.allocation_unit_id
left join sys.partitions p
  on ( au.type in (1,3) and au.container_id = p.hobt_id )
    or
     ( au.type = 2 and au.container_id = p.partition_id )
where database_id = 2
```

Also you can try to [examine a few of the pages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2006/06/10/how-to-use-dbcc-page/) from Tempdb to see if the page header and data gives you any indication of where they are from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried that  on both a 7965 byte empty page and a 40 byte 
 empty page and it gave me minus values on m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = -1778284710  Metadata: IndexId = -1 (examples).  From this source (https://simplesqlserver.com/2016/01/05/tempdb-memory-leak/)  it said:   "The m_objId is a negative value I can’t find in TempDB.sys.objects, so it WAS a temporary object that no longer exists". So they are objects that no longer exist? I added the DBCC page output to the post.

Comment: @RandiVertongen You mentioned there not being any open transactions, how did you verify that?

Comment: @craig by using dbcc opentran and checking sys.dm_exec_requests. also killed of some old connections from the jump server

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this query and send the output?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
(DATEDIFF(n, dtat.transaction_begin_time, GETDATE())) as duration, *
FROM 
sys.dm_tran_active_transactions dtat 
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions dtst 
ON dtat.transaction_id = dtst.transaction_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions es 
ON dtst.session_id = es.session_id
WHERE es.session_id > 50
```

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: Hi Craig, just wanted to say the client is somebody where we rarely go to (once each three months) I asked the Sysadmin to run the query and report the results, but nothing was returned as of yet. I will ofcourse keep you and this question updated. I did ask for a restart (since i set tempdb to a smaller size), which should clear it up if active transactions where the culprit. Either way, I will keep you posted, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi @RandiVertongen, did you set the tempdb files to a fixed size? You probably already know about the risks of that, so sorry if I'm being master of the obvious.

Comment: Hey Craig, no problem, always best to be sure. I set them to 512MB with 256MB Autogrowth, which means they might autogrow more frequently, but I want them to stay as small as possible.

Comment: They tried the restart but they report the same issues. I have the output of the query after the restart, but i think that it does not matter now?

Comment: It seems to be at 6GB memory used for now, still too much, but it is less (unless it rises at certain times or takes longer to reach its full potential)

Comment: @RandiVertongen, it would be interesting to see the output if there is any, so please add it.

Comment: Its a big one, added it in parts but it is not really clear. Will try to filter

Comment: I filtered out some parts like domain and other unneeded stuff.

Comment: @RandiVertongen, yes, don't see any open transactions on tempdb. My only other thought is running this again when you suspect that something is filling tempdb and no one else should be connected.